# Replace column values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

I recently got into SSIS and haven't been able to find what I am trying to achieve anywhere on the web.

I am trying to take some rows as input, and then replace one specific column's value with something else, and then return the rows with modified columns as output.

The problem is that I don't know which task to use.

I'm limited by SQL Server 2008.

How do I get started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I would do this is with a [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx).  Take a look at this example (hitting the sample database, AdventureWorks2012):

[image]

As you can see on this screenshot, what I'm doing is taking the `Name` column from `AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department` (this would work with your version of SQL Server/SSIS as well, I believe.  Although you would know pretty quickly if it doesn't) and using a conditional statement for my *Expression*:

```
Name == "Sales" ? "New Sales Name" : Name
```

What that is, is a short-hand conditional statement.  It takes the Boolean result of `Name == "Sales"`.  If that's true (i.e. the `Name` is "Sales") then return "New Sales Name", or whatever string you'd want to substitute.  If that's false (the `Name` is not "Sales") then just return the `Name` as it originally was.